# Cannot (remote) connect Mac mongo client to Raspberry pi mongod

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi

I am running the "default" mongodb on the Rasp Pi.  I cannot connect to mongod running on my Raspberry Pi from my Mac running a mongo client. I can connect to the web page (my ip:28017...http://192.168.86.20:28017/).  I made all the tweeks on the Raspberry pi I needed to make (opening the ports (results below), modification to mongodb.conf bind_ip parameter (see below).

### Why am I not able to connect from my Mac client?  Thank you.

The error I get through the mongo client on the Mac is:

```
$ mongo --host 192.168.86.20
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.86.20:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-02-09T03:56:39.564-0800 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.86.20:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 192.168.86.20:27017 :: caused by :: Operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-02-09T03:56:39.568-0800 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-02-09T03:56:39.568-0800 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Version of mongod on Raspberry pi:

```
> db.version()
2.4.14
```

version of mongo client on mac:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
```

Raspberry Pi:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'Model'
Model       : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```

Version of Raspbian:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

The ports are available:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

The mongodb.conf bind_ip has been set:

```
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
#port = 27017
```

Comment: Can you ping the Raspberry Pi from your Mac?

Comment: Yes.  I can ssh.  I can get to the web page 28017....